# Substitute double with single quotes

Tags: string, bash, quotes

I need to evaluate length of every filename in the directory. Here's what i do:

```
files=$(ls -Q)
for file in $files;
do
    echo lenght: ${#file}
done
```

But length is calculated with double-quotes (+2). How can i escape that?

Comment: check [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), [and this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse the output of `ls`, use a wildcard and `for`:

```
for file in * ; do
    echo "$file: ${#file}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `ls` for this, and you're experiencing some of why it's [dangerous/tricky](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of ls

you could just do

```
for file in *; do
    echo "length: ${#file}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use the '-Q' flag then?
If you leave it out you get the actual length of the filename.

Comment: Unless a file name contains a space.